# Colored noises: Stationary or non-stationary?

Tags: noise, sound, color, stationary

I know for sure that white noise is considered as a stationary sound, but is that true for the rest of them? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise
Also, can we meet some of these sounds in nature? Is there any relation between these noises and noises that you can hear in a town(vehices,traffic,people chatting) or are these noises just an artificial invention?

Thanks in advance for your ideas and thoughts!:)

Answer (score 3):

Stationary processes have a spectrum that's time-independent. As the Wikipedia link shows, the colored noises each have a characteristic spectrum, are therefore not time-dependent, and thus stationary.

Comment: One case that can be confusing is Brown(ian) Noise. It is non-stationary and not named after a color; rather it is named after Robert Brown.

Comment: @John: Wait, what? You must be using some other definition of "stationary" than [what I'm used to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process).

Comment: Try plotting the cumulative sum of 10 million samples of standard normal distrubuted noise (zero mean, unit variance). This is what Brownian Noise looks like. It also looks like the non-stationary example in your link.

Comment: what type of stationarity are we speaking strick sense or weak sense

Comment: @Barnaby: Strict.

Comment: Thank you. How could I generate a general noise generation function where I could generate individual noise colors

Comment: @Barnaby: Please don't put questions like that down in comments. If there's no answer on the existing StackExcahnge sites (DSP or others), do ask a new question.

Comment: My appologies I forgot to erase it as I was asking in on a separate question